# fading in and out article cards

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am still a beginner at vue and quasar and I would like to animate this Article Container.

```
<template>
    <div class="row align-center q-gutter-md">
        <ArticleCard v-for="(article, index) in currentSlice" :article="article" :key="index"/>
    </div>
    <q-btn rounded label="next" @click="changeSlice" class="self-center"></q-btn>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

import ArticleCard from './ArticleCard.vue';
const props = defineProps({
    articles: Array,
    articlesShowed: Number
});

const currentEnd = ref(props.articlesShowed);

const currentSlice = ref(props.articles.slice(0, currentEnd.value));

const changeSlice = () => {
    currentSlice.value = props.articles.slice(currentEnd.value, currentEnd.value + props.articlesShowed);
    currentEnd.value += props.articlesShowed;
}

</script>
```

and this is my card

```
<template>
    <transition 
        :duration="1000"
        enter-active-class="animated fadeIn"
        leave-active-class="animated fadeOut"
    >
        <q-card class="q-pa-md">
            <q-card-section>
                <div class="text-h6">{{ props.article.title }}</div>
                <q-separator inset></q-separator>
            </q-card-section>
            <q-card-section>{{ article.description }}</q-card-section>
        </q-card>
    </transition>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    article: Object
});
</script>
```

For some reason this transition does not work. Technically, I believe that this happens because the card is not toggled, I am merely changing the content inside of it. Could someone pin down the problems, and give me some hints or advices?

Comment: You're correct that it's because the card is not toggled.  `<transition>` is only for animating the wrapped element as it enters or leaves the DOM (usually controlled via `v-if` directive).  For other types of animations you'll need to use standard CSS